# Unable to get navigation bar inline with logo

Tags: css, html, user-interface

I'm trying to get my navigation bar on my html page inline with my logo however it wont budge. I assume its because its following the flow of the html page, I dont really want to use absolute positioning, i did try and use the 'left' and 'top' properties in css however it didnt like it. Please could you advise where I'm going wrong?

Please see example here:[demo of problem](http://jsfiddle.net/Lj9yn/2/)

P.s. The red was just to help me see what was going on.

Comment: You've got a stray `</li>` tag after the `<p>` tag that (invalidly) contains the `<h1>`. So your HTML is invalid, which is likely to make things worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few errors with your HTML structure, some unclosed tags, and odd placement of elements.  I have reworked the code for you to see an example that works for modern browsers.  It's not the cleanest code but it should get you on the right path.  http://jsfiddle.net/Lj9yn/18/